# Rank and determinant of the image of a vector bundle after applying a Schur functor?

Tags: vector-bundles, determinants, schur-functors

Let $\mathcal{E}$ be a vector bundle of rank $r$ and degree $d$ over some smooth projective variety $X$. Furthermore, let $\lambda$ be a partition of $n$. We apply the $\lambda$-th Schur functor to $\mathcal{E}$, namely $S^{λ}(\mathcal{E})$. What is its rank and its degree?

As a first concrete case to start with, we assume $X$ to be the Grassmannian $\mathbb{G}(k,N)$ and $\mathcal{E}$ to be the dual of the tautological subbundle $\mathcal{U}$ -- i.e. $\mathcal{E}$ has highest weight $\omega_1$). If we apply the Schur functor $S^\lambda$ with $\lambda=(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,...,\lambda_k,0,...0)$, then we want to compute $$\mathrm{rk} \; S^{\lambda}(\mathcal{U}^\vee)$$ as well as $$\mathrm{det} \; S^{\lambda}(\mathcal{U}^\vee).$$

I would be happy if someone cloud present a closed formula in terms of the entries $\lambda_i$'s or another algorithmic approach to this problem. If there is some nice statement in the literature where I can deduce from such formula, I would be happy to have the reference.

Comment: The rank would be given by the Weyl dimensional formula for a highest weight representation of $GL(\mathcal{E})$ , no? 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_character_formula#Weyl_dimension_formula

Comment: It seems to me that this question is overly complicated. Surely you'll get the same answer just for a vector space. So the rank is given by the hook formula (see for example the book of Gordon James, "Representations of general linear groups") and the degree is just $n$. Or am I missing something?